# HttpSecurity not working with Spring Boot 1.1.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement a OAuth2 security in my mobile app back-end side based on [this](https://github.com/juleswhite/mobilecloud-14/tree/master/examples/9-VideoServiceWithOauth2) example.

The example uses `springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE'`. In my project I'm using 1.1.7.RELEASE. After having several inexplicable 400 - Bad Requests, I started pairing the dependencies.

So when I set the example spring boot version equal to mine, it stop compiling. Specifically the methods between **.** cannot be found.

```
// This method configures the OAuth scopes required by clients to access
        // all of the paths in the video service.
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.**csrf**().disable();
            http
                    .**authorizeRequests**()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").anonymous();
            http
                    .**authorizeRequests**()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**")
                    .access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')");
            http
                    .**authorizeRequests**()
                    .antMatchers("/**")
                    .access("#oauth2.hasScope('write')");
        }
        }
```

I believe the relevant gradle dependencies to the security in the application are:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:${springBootVersion}")
compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.0.RC2")
compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2-javaconfig:1.0.0.M1")
```

These are the original ones found in the example. Interesting, however, is that in my application I never get compiling erros, but it also does not work. My test cases running with the example application up run fine.

I'm really confused here. Should I change any of those dependencies? Thanks in advance for any support.

**EDIT**

Simple greeting controller:

```
public interface GreetingSvcApi {
    public static final String GREETING_PATH = "/greeting";
    @GET(GREETING_PATH)
    public Greeting greeting(@Query("name") String name);
}

@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping(value = GreetingSvcApi.GREETING_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "Hello Developer") String name) {
        return new Greeting(name);
    }
}

public class GreetingControllerTest extends TestCase {

    private final String USERNAME = "admin";
    private final String PASSWORD = "pass";
    private final String CLIENT_ID = "mobile";
    private final String READ_ONLY_CLIENT_ID = "mobileReader";

    private GreetingSvcApi greetingService = new SecuredRestBuilder()
            .setLoginEndpoint(RestDataFixture.SERVER_HTTPS + BaseServiceApi.TOKEN_PATH)
            .setUsername(USERNAME)
            .setPassword(PASSWORD)
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setClient(new ApacheClient(UnsafeHttpsClient.createUnsafeClient()))
            .setEndpoint(RestDataFixture.SERVER_HTTPS).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build()
            .create(GreetingSvcApi.class);

    public void testGreetingInHttp() throws Exception {

        Greeting greeting = greetingService.greeting("Greeting");
        assertEquals(greeting.getPerson(), "Greeting");
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://localhost:8443
o.a.h.i.c.HttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:8443
o.a.h.i.c.HttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 127.0.0.1:57518<->127.0.0.1:8443
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Basic bW9iaWxlOg==
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 80
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: localhost:8443
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: Basic bW9iaWxlOg==[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 80[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8443[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "username=admin&password=pass&client_id=mobile&client_secret=&grant_type=password"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Expires: 0[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Frame-Options: DENY[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Application-Context: application[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-store[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/hal+json[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 19:03:42 GMT[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "75[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "{"access_token":"1a59e04c-afb0-40cd-9e17-4e573beea347","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43199,"scope":"read write"}[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Pragma: no-cache
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Expires: 0
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Frame-Options: DENY
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Application-Context: application
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-store
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Pragma: no-cache
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/hal+json
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 19:03:42 GMT
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443] can be kept alive indefinitely
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
---> HTTP GET https://localhost:8443/greeting?name=Greeting
Authorization: Bearer 1a59e04c-afb0-40cd-9e17-4e573beea347
---> END HTTP (no body)
o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Stale connection check
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request GET /greeting?name=Greeting HTTP/1.1
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> GET /greeting?name=Greeting HTTP/1.1
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Bearer 1a59e04c-afb0-40cd-9e17-4e573beea347
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: localhost:8443
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "GET /greeting?name=Greeting HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: Bearer 1a59e04c-afb0-40cd-9e17-4e573beea347[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8443[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Expires: 0[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Frame-Options: DENY[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8FC93D46387663ED9D1EA7F97C7F9B45; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Application-Context: application[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/hal+json[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 19:03:42 GMT[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "2a[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "{"person":"Greeting","date":1414782222693}[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Pragma: no-cache
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Expires: 0
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Frame-Options: DENY
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8FC93D46387663ED9D1EA7F97C7F9B45; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Application-Context: application
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/hal+json
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 19:03:42 GMT
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
o.a.h.c.p.ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie accepted [JSESSIONID="8FC93D46387663ED9D1EA7F97C7F9B45", version:0, domain:localhost, path:/, expiry:null]
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443] can be kept alive indefinitely
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
<--- HTTP 200 https://localhost:8443/greeting?name=Greeting (324ms)
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8FC93D46387663ED9D1EA7F97C7F9B45; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/hal+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 19:03:42 GMT

{"person":"Greeting","date":1414782222693}
<--- END HTTP (42-byte body)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Actual output:

```
o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://localhost:8443
o.a.h.i.c.HttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:8443
o.a.h.i.c.HttpClientConnectionOperator - Connection established 127.0.0.1:55456<->127.0.0.1:8443
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Executing request POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Authorization: Basic bW9iaWxlOg==
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 80
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: localhost:8443
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Authorization: Basic bW9iaWxlOg==[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 80[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localhost:8443[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "username=admin&password=pass&client_id=mobile&client_secret=&grant_type=password"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Expires: 0[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Frame-Options: DENY[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "X-Application-Context: application:8443[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-store[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 18:06:51 GMT[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: close[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "3f[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Pragma: no-cache
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Expires: 0
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Frame-Options: DENY
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << X-Application-Context: application:8443
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-store
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Pragma: no-cache
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 18:06:51 GMT
org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: close
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "0[\r][\n]"
org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
o.a.h.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Close connection
o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://localhost:8443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
---- ERROR 
org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestException: org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestException: Login failure: 400 - Bad Request
    at org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestBuilder$OAuthHandler.intercept(SecuredRestBuilder.java:150)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:300)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.greeting(Unknown Source)
    at org.portotech.pague360mpayments.rest.controller.GreetingControllerTest.testGreetingInHttp(GreetingControllerTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestException: Login failure: 400 - Bad Request
    at org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestBuilder$OAuthHandler.intercept(SecuredRestBuilder.java:138)
    ... 26 more

---- END ERROR

retrofit.RetrofitError: org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestException: Login failure: 400 - Bad Request
    at retrofit.RetrofitError.unexpectedError(RetrofitError.java:44)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.greeting(Unknown Source)
    at org.portotech.pague360mpayments.rest.controller.GreetingControllerTest.testGreetingInHttp(GreetingControllerTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestException: org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestException: Login failure: 400 - Bad Request
    at org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestBuilder$OAuthHandler.intercept(SecuredRestBuilder.java:150)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:300)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestException: Login failure: 400 - Bad Request
    at org.portotech.pague360mpayments.security.SecuredRestBuilder$OAuthHandler.intercept(SecuredRestBuilder.java:138)
    ... 26 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: I guess a lot of people are doing that course because I'm seeing the same code a lot. It's a bit of a bizarre example (someone should tell the author to contact me for a chat and maybe he can explain it to me). But I have no idea why you would have a compile error on those methods since they are not new. Do you just need to refresh the IDE or something? You don't really say what is not working "in my application", so some more detail is probably a good idea.

Comment: Hi Dave. Yes, I imagine it is a not very good code, maybe for just educational purposes. Refreshing the IDE is not working, I even had cleaned my gradle cache and everything else is possible in that direction. What I can do is to generate a token for a client. I'm gonna paste both outputs in my question, the correct one and my one.

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm looking at. I thought you said there were compile errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the strange implementation of the sample app referred to, there is (or was) an issue in Spring Boot making thing difficult [gh-1801](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1801). A workaround is described there, and also used in [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/9d21b2aa3d8f3f1a4d0da4551355520dc7d7b72d/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/Application.java#L87).